Setup user defined list of figures
I have created a "map" environment as an alternative to the figure environment and am now trying to set up the associated list.

How do I modify how these entries appear in the list of maps -- specifically, display "Map 1", ... as I have been able to set in the list of figures and tables ?

How do I remove the page break before the List of maps?


Here is my code as it stands:
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

%% Create map environment

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=map,
  float,
  name=Map,
  listname={List of maps},
  ]{map}


\usepackage{tocloft}
% Format appearance of list of figures
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0 em} 
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\cftfigpagefont{\footnotesize}
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{-0.75 em}

% Format appearance of list of tables
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0 em}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{4 em}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\cfttabpagefont{\footnotesize}
\setlength\cftbeforetabskip{-0.75 em}

% Format appearance of list of maps
%% ?


\begin{document}

% A Figure
\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

% A Table
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

% A Map
\begin{map}[!h]
\caption{A map}
\end{map}

%-- Lists --%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{My list of figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{My list of tables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables

\renewcommand{\listmapname}{My list of maps}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listmapname}
\listofmaps

\end{document}


I would not recommend to mix tocbasic and tocloft. So I would recommend to either do all the configurations using tocbasic or define the new TOC using another package. Nevertheless, if you use tocbasic you can use all the entry features of the package already when defining the new TOC, e.g.:
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

%% Create map environment

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=map,
  float,
  name=Map,
  listname={My list of maps},
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentryindent=0em,
  tocentrynumwidth=6em,
  tocentryformat=\footnotesize,
  tocentryentrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{Map~},
  tocentrypagenumberformat=\footnotesize,
  ]{map}
\setuptoc{map}{totoc}
\deftocheading{map}{{\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{#1}}}% I would not
                             % recommend this, but you've asked for it
\AfterTOCHead[map]{\vspace{-.75em}}% I would not recommend this, but you've
                                % asked for it

\newcommand*{\entrynumberwithprefix}[2]{#1#2}

\usepackage{tocloft}
% Format appearance of list of figures
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0 em} 
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\cftfigpagefont{\footnotesize}
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{-0.75 em}

% Format appearance of list of tables
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0 em}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{4 em}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\cfttabpagefont{\footnotesize}
\setlength\cftbeforetabskip{-0.75 em}

% Format appearance of list of maps
%% ?


\begin{document}

% A Figure
\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

% A Table
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

% A Map
\begin{map}[!h]
\caption{A map}
\end{map}

%-- Lists --%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{My list of figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{My list of tables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables

\listofmaps% Note: the entry to the table of contents is done using \setuptoc

\end{document}


An IMHO cleaner solution would be to use tocbasic also for the configuration of the list of figures and the list of tables. Additionally I would not use the inconsistency of a chapter head without page break for the headings of all the ToCs. Instead I would aggregate all these ToCs as sections to a new chapter:
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

%% Create map environment

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=map,
  float,
  name=Map,
  listname={My list of maps},
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentryindent=0em,
  tocentrynumwidth=6em,
  tocentryformat=\footnotesize,
  tocentryentrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{Map~},
  tocentrypagenumberformat=\footnotesize,
  ]{map}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  indent=0em,
  numwidth=6em,
  entryformat=\footnotesize,
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{Figure~},
  pagenumberformat=\footnotesize,
]{tocline}{figure}
\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[My list of figures]{lof}}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  indent=0em,
  numwidth=6em,
  entryformat=\footnotesize,
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{Table~},
  pagenumberformat=\footnotesize,
]{tocline}{table}
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[My list of tables]{lot}}
\newcommand*{\entrynumberwithprefix}[2]{#1#2}
\setuptoc{lof}{totoc}
\setuptoc{lot}{totoc}
\setuptoc{map}{totoc}
\setuptoc{lof}{leveldown}
\setuptoc{lot}{leveldown}
\setuptoc{map}{leveldown}

\begin{document}

% A Figure
\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

% A Table
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

% A Map
\begin{map}[!h]
\caption{A map}
\end{map}

% -- Lists --%
\chapter*{My lists}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{My lists}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofmaps

\end{document}


Or even easier, with using a KOMA-Script class:
\documentclass[listof=entryprefix,listof=graduated,listof=totoc,listof=leveldown,chapterprefix,sfdefaults=false]{scrreprt}

%% Create map environment

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=map,
  float,
  nonfloat,
  name=Map,
  listname={My list of maps},
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentryindent=0em,
  tocentrynumwidth=6em,
  tocentryformat=\footnotesize,
  tocentrypagenumberformat=\footnotesize,
  ]{map}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
  indent=0em,
  numwidth=6em,
  entryformat=\footnotesize,
  pagenumberformat=\footnotesize,
]{tocline}{figure,table}

\begin{document}

% A Figure
\begin{figure-}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure-}

% A Table
\begin{table-}
\caption{A table}
\end{table-}

% A Map
\begin{map-}
\caption{A map}
\end{map-}

% -- Lists --%
\addchap{My lists}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofmaps

\end{document}



I receive the following error: ! Package keyval Error: tocentrystyle undefined. compiling with XeLaTex. Am I missing a package somewhere?

@user2568648 With my examples? It seems you are using a very, very old TeX installation. The option is available since KOMA-Script v3.20 released on 2016-05-10. If so, you should update. As a workaround you may try to move the tocentry… options without the prefix tocentry to one more \DeclareTOCStyleEntry similar to that for figure and table. But I cannot test it with such an old KOMA-Script. The oldest I've available is 2019/02/01 v3.26b.

Update solved the problem... had a VERY old version running.
